# Не работает DisplayDateStart в DatePicker

Tags: wpf, дата, datepicker, display

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуста, как вы настраиваете `DatePicker`, чтобы показывал начальный год не `0001`? Везде говорят, что за это отвечает  `DisplayDateStart`, но у меня не работает, может я его неправильно использую?
Заранее спасибо

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PickDateVente" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" 
     SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentVente.DateVente}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="140" 
     FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" DisplayDateStart="1/1/2017"></DatePicker>
```

Comment: У меня ваш пример работает нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `DatePicker` показывает значение которое получает объект `DateTime` по умолчанию:

```
> Console.WriteLine(new DateTime());
01.01.0001 0:00:00
```

Свойство `DisplayDateStart` действительно отвечает за настройку диапазона отображаемрой даты (а именно нижнего предела), но поскольку значение `SelectedDate` меньше чем то, которое вы указываете в `DisplayDateStart` вы видите именно такую дату. Таким образом ваша нижняя граница будет смещена.

То есть, если бы вы, к примеру, инициализировали `DateVente` следующим значением

```
DateTime.Parse("15.10.2016")
```

то это была бы минимально допустимая для выбора дата, несмотря на то, что вы в свойстве `DisplayDateStart` явно указываете другое (`DisplayDateStart="1/1/2017"`)

Поэтому вам нужно определиться с тем, какую дату вы хотите отображать по 
умолчанию (например, сегодня) и инициализировать свойство в конструкторе:

```
public CurrentVente()
{
    DateVente = DateTime.Now;
}
```

или используя инициализатор свойств:

```
public class CurrentVente
{
     public DateTime DateVente { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Тогда вы не сможете выбрать дату выходящую из указанного диапазона.

Добавлю также, что вместе с нижним можно задавать и верхний предел за установку которого отвечает свойство `DisplayDateEnd`

Comment: Спасибо! раотает